# window.stop() in componentWillUnmount() cancels the requests made in componentWillMount() for components that are not yet mounted

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, request, request-cancelling

I have problems cancelling pending requests on my React application. I am trying to use `window.stop()` in the following way:

I have enqueued the following list of requests:

[image: List of pending requests]

What I want is to cancel the pending requests when I exit from that page but not the new ones that are made by the new component. For that, I found `window.stop()` method which cancels all the pending requests, so I try to execute on `componentWillUnmount()`:

```js
  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.stop();
  }
```

However, if the next mounted component executes another request in `componentWillMount()`, this is cancelled too, which I want to avoid:

[image: projects/]

The execution flow is as follows:

1. I go to **page1** and this enqueue and execute all the paginated requests of the image [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZHorN.png).
2. Before all requests are finished, I go to **page2** using `useNavigate()` and some click event.
3. The `componentWillMount()` of **page2** is executed and makes the new request `projects/`.
4. The `componentWillUnmount()` of **page1** is executed and all the pending requests are cancelled, including the new one made by **page2**.

I create this minimal reproducible example. The specified behaviour happens when I am in page1 waiting for the responses off the three requests and I move to page 2 by clicking the button. You can see how all the requests, including the new one of the page2, are cancelled  [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-sky-8hq45d?file=/src/api.js)

In our code, we are doing neccesary requests of the different pages in `componentWillMount()` that as I know, is executed before `componentWillUnmount()` which is the reason for this behaviour. My question is:
I have to change all the `componentWillMount()` of my code with
`componentDidMount()` if I want to cancel all the request except the new ones that are made when the new component is mounted? Or is there another way to implement this?

Thanks you in advance!

Comment: We can't really address issues in code we can't see. Can you [edit] to include a relevant [mcve] so we can see what any of the code you are using is doing?

Comment: You are using (*effectively*) deprecated React code. `componentWillMount` hasn't been recommended to use for years. If you are still using React class components then you should use the `componentDidMount` lifecycle method. It is rather unclear what you are trying to accomplish overall. If you are simply trying to cancel in-flight network requests then you should an [abort controller](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortController). See [axios cancellation](https://axios-http.com/docs/cancellation) for how to do this with axios.

Comment: It looks like the sandbox code is working as expected, but since it is unclear really what you want it to do then perhaps it isn't working as you are expecting and that hasn't been clearly explained.